# WCF hosted in Windows service close all connections after some time

Tags: sockets, wcf, connection-refused

we are facing an issue with WCF service hosted in a Windows service with net.tcp binding.
After some time it closes all connection (we see it in real time with TCPView). We noticed this behavior because in the client application log we find errors of TCP connection refused 10061. When all connection are close it starts to accept new conections. All firewall and antivirus has been disabled. RAM and CPU are ok.
What can I look for?

Thanks

Comment: How many connections are open when it closes all? Why are they open?

Comment: The connections are opened beacuse there are clients that connect to the WCF service to obtain data to process. There are about 200 connections

Comment: What is the client behavior? Is it keeps channel open ?

Comment: Yes each channel is kept open and poll each minute to ask for data

Comment: We need more data - the wcf configuration and what is the load  how many concurrent calls and example to the client behavior

Comment: Have you tried to control concurrency below 200 by configuring throttling?<serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="mythrottling">
            <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="100" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="20"/>
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

Comment: When Windows start, a little application starts and put itself in the tray area. It open a connection with a WPF service with net.tcp binding. Each minute call WCF for data to process. The configuration fo server WCF is <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="1000" maxConcurrentInstances="1048576" maxConcurrentSessions="200"/> 
In practice, the client application works only if there are data. Could it be useful to turn the way of working in push mode? With which advantages?
Thanks

Comment: throttling technology is to solve the problem of system crash caused by insufficient computing power of the processor. I suggest you try to reduce concurrency session/call to cope with high loads.

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? we are facing same issue. please advise